# Create a computer lab using Linux

Tags: networking, files, users

I would like to know, how I can create my own Linux lab, like the universities Linux labs. I mean OK, I can install for example Fedora to all my 4 PCs, but how I can login from different computers, and be able to have access to my files from any out of the 4 PCs?

In addition how can I login at all 4 using the same password? I know that it should be a server behind all that containing my files, or login info, but how all these are connected?

And how I can ensure security on that lab (eg, not be able for a user to install a malware, and how I cannot for example see or copy files of other users)?

Answer (score 1):

Devote a machine or VM to an LDAP server. This will provide authentication to all of the machines.

Devote a machine with lots of storage to provide a centralized file store via NFS. You can hold home directories here and globally installed software exported to /home and /usr/global.

Devote a VM to CUPS to provide centralized printing.

Comment: Many thanks. And if I told you for example that I am a company, and I have many users, but I want *everything* to be secured, would you propose the same things?

Comment: Its exactly as secure as you configure it, since the proposed solution uses a centralized NFS file storage, it offers the same security features as you are used to. If you allow users to install software, then yes, they can install malware. If you don't allow them to, then no, they cant.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be a terminal server http://www.ltsp.org/ , which is quite common in computer labs as well.